# Can openmdao compute partial derivatives across a Matlab ExternalCodeComp without explicitly defining them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, optimization, openmdao

Is it possible to have openmdao to approximate partial the derivatives across the ExternalCodeComp using finite difference.

Just by using the method `self.declare_partials('*','*', method='fd')` seems not to work
Optimization converges after 1 iteration with only 1 function and gradient evaluations.

The error that pop ups :
DerivativesWarning:Constraints or objectives [('p.f_xy', inds=[0])] cannot be impacted by the design variables of the problem.
DerivativesWarning:Design variables [('p.x', inds=[0]), ('p.y', inds=[0])] have no impact on the constraints or objective.
Optimization terminated successfully .

Answer (score 3):

We run a test case very similar to this as part of the OpenMDAO test suite. Your `declare_partials` call is not quite correct because you list the first two args as '' and '' which would not match any variable names.  I suspect that's just a typo in your post though because if you actually ran OpenMDAO while using those args you would get an exception telling you that the declared partials didn't match any variables.  In the example shown below I declare the partials as `self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='fd')`.  Assuming that your partials are actually declared correctly, my guess is that for some reason the output file that your external code is generating is either not getting updated at all or you're always writing the same values to the output file.  Below is a working example of an external code that computes a paraboloid.  Hopefully that will help you track down the issue.  If not, you can try posting your code here and we can go from there.

Here's the OpenMDAO script:

```
import sys
import openmdao.api as om


class ParaboloidExternalCodeCompFD(om.ExternalCodeComp):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', val=0.0)
        self.add_input('y', val=0.0)

        self.add_output('f_xy', val=0.0)

        self.input_file = 'paraboloid_input.dat'
        self.output_file = 'paraboloid_output.dat'

        # providing these is optional; the component will verify that any input
        # files exist before execution and that the output files exist after.
        self.options['external_input_files'] = [self.input_file]
        self.options['external_output_files'] = [self.output_file]

        self.options['command'] = [
            sys.executable, 'extcode_paraboloid.py', self.input_file, self.output_file
        ]

    def setup_partials(self):
        # this external code does not provide derivatives, use finite difference
        self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='fd')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        x = inputs['x']
        y = inputs['y']

        # generate the input file for the paraboloid external code
        with open(self.input_file, 'w') as input_file:
            input_file.write('%.16f\n%.16f\n' % (x, y))

        # the parent compute function actually runs the external code
        super().compute(inputs, outputs)

        # parse the output file from the external code and set the value of f_xy
        with open(self.output_file, 'r') as output_file:
            f_xy = float(output_file.read())

        outputs['f_xy'] = f_xy


prob = om.Problem()
model = prob.model

model.add_subsystem('p', ParaboloidExternalCodeCompFD())

# find optimal solution with SciPy optimize
# solution (minimum): x = 6.6667; y = -7.3333
prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('p.x', lower=-50, upper=50)
prob.model.add_design_var('p.y', lower=-50, upper=50)

prob.model.add_objective('p.f_xy')

prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True

prob.setup()

# Set input values
prob.set_val('p.x', 3.0)
prob.set_val('p.y', -4.0)

prob.run_driver()

print('p.x =', prob.get_val('p.x'), "  expected:", [6.66666667])
print('p.x =', prob.get_val('p.y'), "  expected:", [-7.3333333])
```

And here's the external code script, which is named `extcode_paraboloid.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# usage: extcode_paraboloid.py input_filename output_filename
#
# Evaluates the equation f(x,y) = (x-3)^2 + xy + (y+4)^2 - 3.
#
# Read the values of `x` and `y` from input file
# and write the value of `f_xy` to output file.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    input_filename = sys.argv[1]
    output_filename = sys.argv[2]

    with open(input_filename, 'r') as input_file:
        file_contents = input_file.readlines()

    x, y = [float(f) for f in file_contents]

    f_xy = (x-3.0)**2 + x*y + (y+4.0)**2 - 3.0

    with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write('%.16f\n' % f_xy)
```

If you place them both in the same directory and run the OpenMDAO script, you should get something like:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: -27.333333333333
            Iterations: 5
            Function evaluations: 6
            Gradient evaluations: 5
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
p.x = [6.66666633]   expected: [6.66666667]
p.x = [-7.33333367]   expected: [-7.3333333]
```